# How to build a view for tables in Universe in BO 4.1?

Tags: business-objects

How can we build view for tables in a universe in BO 4.1?

I have build my universe with tables. Now I need to add views for the tables. View script is executed.

How can I add appropriate view for the tables?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the variable names at Business Layer at IDT if thats what you mean as "view".

Comment: I meant like..i have universe that is already build. I need to build Webi reports from Views which is gonna be created. How can i add this views to my universe. DO i need to rebuild completely or can i add the views to my already build universe.

Comment: You can change the name of variables at Business Layer without changing the data foundation and publish the universe again just like this: http://s8.postimg.org/i9p6d4979/img_1.jpg

and also you can insert views from SQL server in same fashion like inserting tables

Comment: ok.. so its like i can take the name of the view created in database level and replace the table name in my IDT with the view name that is created in database.

Comment: Exacly, or you can insert views instead of tables at data foundation lavel and variable names will appear like how it is at database, like this: http://s3.postimg.org/htho2yvnn/img2_1.jpg

Comment: Thanks for explaining in an understanding way.

Answer (score 1):

Views can be added to the universe exactly like tables are.  To the universe, there is no difference between tables and views.

Comment: do you mean that like how we add with insert view in IDT? or something like to run the script or something? please explain.. i am new to this tool.

Comment: No script.  The same steps you follow to insert a table are the same steps you take to insert a view.